# JAVA - Validating User inputs on service methods in a cleaner way

Tags: java, dto

- In a project, we use service methods, there, we have to validate certain required inputs for our business logic to work:

```java
public void exampleMethod(final UserDto user, String sthElse) {
    if (user.getId() == null) {
      throw new CustomHandledException("example");
    }
    if (sthElse == null) {
      throw new CustomHandledException("example");
    }

    GetUserResponseDto getUserResponse = client.getUserById(user.getId(), country);

    if (getUserResponse == null) {
      if (user.getGivenName() == null) {
        throw new CustomHandledException("example");
      }
      if (user.getEmail() == null) {
        throw new CustomHandledException("example");
      }
      CreateUserRequestDto createUserBody = UserMapper.toCreateBody(user);
      client.createUser(createUserBody);
      return;
    }

    if (user.getLocale().equals(getUserResponse.getUser().getProfile().getLocale())){
        return;
    }

    client.updateUser(user);
  }
```

Even though the code isn't necessarily wrong and is quite understandable (for me) I feel like there is something odd there, do you have any suggestions for a cleaner code?

I tried to write a clean code, however, doesn't feel like it is clean.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you're getting at about it seeming odd. I suppose the various if/throws are repetitive and could be reduced by writing a function for them.

```
private void requireNotNull(boolean requirementMet, String errorMessage) {
    if (requirementMet == null) throw CustomHandledException(errorMessage);
}

// or, depending on whether the messages require any calculations:

private void requireNotNull(boolean requirementMet, Supplier<String> lazyErrorMessage) {
    if (requirementMet == null) throw CustomHandledException(lazyErrorMessage.get());
}
```

This is getting really nitpicky, but I think the logic flow would read slightly easier if you handle the non-null case of `getUserResponse` first so you don't have a big chunk of code in between retrieving something and working with that retrieved thing.

```
public void exampleMethod(final UserDto user, String sthElse) {
    requireNotNull(user.getId(), "example");
    requireNotNull(sthElse, "example");

    GetUserResponseDto getUserResponse = client.getUserById(user.getId(), country);
    if (getUserResponse != null) { 
        Locale currentLocale = getUserResponse.getUser().getProfile().getLocale();
        if (!user.getLocale().equals(currentLocale)) {
            client.updateUser(user);
        }
    } else {
        requireNotNull(user.getGivenName(), "example");
        requireNotNull(user.getEmail(), "example");
        CreateUserRequestDto createUserBody = UserMapper.toCreateBody(user);
        client.createUser(createUserBody);
    }
}
```

Aside from that, I wouldn't start variable names with verbs.

Comment: No need to write `requireNontNull` yourself. Java comes with that: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)

Comment: @RoToRa, depends on whether they specifically need that "CustomHandled" exception.

Answer (score 2):

Separate into any function

```
private void validateInputs(final UserDto user, String sthElse) {
    if (user.getId() == null || sthElse == null) {
        throw new CustomHandledException("example");
    }
    
    if (user.getGivenName() == null || user.getEmail() == null) {
        throw new CustomHandledException("example");
    }
}

private void handleUserCreation(final UserDto user) {
    CreateUserRequestDto createUserBody = UserMapper.toCreateBody(user);
    client.createUser(createUserBody);
}

private void handleUserUpdate(final UserDto user, GetUserResponseDto getUserResponse) {
    if (!user.getLocale().equals(getUserResponse.getUser().getProfile().getLocale())) {
        client.updateUser(user);
    }
}
```

And then combine it in:

```
public void exampleMethod(final UserDto user, String sthElse) {
    validateInputs(user, sthElse);

    GetUserResponseDto getUserResponse = client.getUserById(user.getId(), country);

    if (getUserResponse == null) {
        handleUserCreation(user);
    } else {
        handleUserUpdate(user, getUserResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support, definitely gave me some insights

Comment: I suggest avoiding weak words like "handle" in method names. It doesn't add any meaning to the name, so it becomes a hindrance to readability. These could be "createUser" and "updateUser".